# RStudio launch fails - The R session had a fatal error?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have R and RStudio installed successfully. But I get this error when I first launch RStudio:

[image]

What does it mean? How can I fix it?

I'm on Ubuntu 17.04.

I'm R 3.3 as well:

$ R

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31) -- "Sincere Pumpkin Patch"
Copyright (C) 2016 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.
```

How can I upgrade it to 3.4?

Comment: Is it windows, linux etc?  What is the R/Rstudio versions?

Comment: @akrun based on the error message, I would say Ubuntu.

Comment: @akrun yes it is on Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: Perhaps you need `sudo apt-get install r-base-dev`

Comment: Have you tried another version of Rstudio, like a [daily build](https://www.rstudio.org/download/daily/desktop/ubuntu64/) perhaps?

Comment: I think I should upgrade it to 3.4. how can I do that?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I haven't but I think I should upgrade my R first....